# add state on country array dynamically in js

Tags: javascript

```
var countries = ['India', 'China', 'Malaysia'];

var states = ['Penang', 'Johor', 'KL']; // for Malaysia
```

How can I add the states on related country array? Is that mean country array become 2 dimensional?

Comment: well i dont think two dimensions array works the way you think they work, i thin you are aiming for object rather than array?

Comment: @Yusnee IMO, your question is hard to make sense of. It's not clear what exactly you are asking for, although I'm glad someone figured it out and managed to help you. Don't take downvotes personally, and don't make a fuss about them; they are given for the present state of the question, not the person who asked it. It's usual for questions that seemingly lack research effort to receive a bunch of downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object to describe what a country is, instead of a name:

```
const countries = [{...}, {...}, {
    name: 'Malaysia',
    states: ['Penang', 'Johor', 'KL']
}, {...}];
```

Comment: Hmm... ok I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map()` to change array and make `Malaysia` object with states as value.

```js
var countries = ['India', 'China', 'Malaysia'];
var states = ['Penang', 'Johor', 'KL']; 

var result = countries.map(function(e) {
  if(e == 'Malaysia') { 
    e = {[e]: states}
  } else {
    e = {[e]: []}
  }
  return e;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: you almost there. But I think India and China should be in bracket as well but no array content. And Is it possible using push array?

Comment: Yes result is as expected.